# ddcal is not working

Tags: logic, model-checking, binary-decision-diagram

I am trying to use [DDcal](http://vlsi.colorado.edu/~fabio/) for evaluating binary decision diagrams. 
When I try to evaluate some formula e.g.: `a+b*c'`, I always get this error:

```
util_pipefork: can not exec dot: No such file or directory.
```

Does anyone have idea how I can resolve this error?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Do you have `dot` installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python package [`dd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd) for working with BDDs using either the Python or CUDD backends (disclaimer: I'm `dd`'s author). Example:

```py
import dd.autoref as _bdd  # to use CUDD, replace `dd.bdd` with `dd.cudd`

bdd = _bdd.BDD()
bdd.declare('a', 'b', 'c')
u = bdd.add_expr(r'a \/ (b /\ ~ c)')
```

The syntax is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/doc.md#syntax-for-quantified-boolean-formulae). If you prefer writing `a | (b & ~ c)`, that works too. The pure Python backend is installed with `pip install dd`.

You can also plot using `dot` (assuming [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) is installed):

```py
bdd.dump('bdd_graph.pdf')
```

The method `BDD.dump` is described [here](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/01d917382cad24f0d48cde3f2ea2759e8a9a5544/dd/bdd.py#L1107).

### About DDcal's message

`grep -ilr "util_pipefork" ./*` says that the error you reported from [DDcal](http://vlsi.colorado.edu/%7Efabio/) seems to be coming from the following lines:

```c
/* Set up bidirectional pipe to/from dot. */
/* A unidirectional pipe should suffice. We'll try it some day. */
retval = util_pipefork(args,&toCommand,&fromCommand,&pid);
if (retval == 0) {
(void) fprintf(stderr,"Panic: util_pipefork returned 0!\n");
exit(2);
}
```

So, you need to install [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org), and make sure that its executables (in particular `dot`) are in the [runtime environment's `$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).